# Can the OpenACC tasks in the same stream run concurrently under async clause effect?

Tags: parallel-processing, openacc

I am learning *OpenACC* now, I have seen the definition which allow the parallel running using async clause in *OpenACC* specification, but I don't know whether the multi tasks which all use async clause and assign to the same stream can run concurrently or not?

Anyone know or have any clue to find out?

Answer (score 1):

Regions with the same async queue number are completed in order, but regions with different queue numbers operate independently and can (but aren't guaranteed to) run concurrently. When there's no queue number the work goes into a default queue. Queue numbers are per-device.